# Captcha code used to sign up form is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I would to like to create a sign up form using Captcha in `php` with `mysql` data.  Anytime I submit the form, the Captcha code shows  an error. But when I check my database connecting code is working. The code is below.

> signup.php

```
    <?php                                                       
    session_start();                                                            
    ?>                                                                  
   <!DOCTYPE html>                                                         
   enter code here<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Registration Form with PHP Captcha Demo</title>
<meta name="title" content="Registration Form with PHP Captcha Demo"/>
<meta name="description" content=""/>
<meta name="keywords" content=""/>

<link href="css/style_demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".refresh").click(function () {
    $(".imgcaptcha").attr("src","demo_captcha.php?_="+((new Date()).getTime()));

});


 $('#register').submit(function() {

 if($('#password').val() != $('#cpassword').val()){
    alert("Please re-enter confirm password");
    $('#cpassword').val('');
    $('#cpassword').focus();
    return false;
 }
    $.post("submit_demo_captcha.php?"+$("#register").serialize(), { }, function(response){
        if(response==0){
           $(".imgcaptcha").attr("src","demo_captcha.php?_="+((new Date()).getTime()));
           clear_form();
           alert("Data Submitted Successfully.")
        }else{
           alert("wrong captcha code!");
        }
    });
    return false;
    });


     function clear_form()
     {
        $("#fname").val('');
        $("#lname").val('');
        $("#username").val('');
        $("#email").val('');
        $("#dob").val('');
        $("#gender").val('');
        $("#password").val('');
        $("#cpassword").val('');
        $("#captcha").val('');
     }


});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="bodyfull">
<div id="bodyfull2">
    <div id="center">

        <div class="inner_right_demo"> 
        <form name="register" action="#null" method="post" id="register">
            <div class="form_box">
                <div>
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your First Name" id="fname" name="fname" required="required">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name" id="lname" name="lname" required="required">
                </div>

                 <div>
                    <label>User Name</label>
                    <input type="text"  placeholder="Enter Your User Name" id="username" name="username" required="required">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address" id="email" name="email" required="required">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>Date of birth</label>
                    <input type="date"  id="dob" name="dob">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>Gender</label>
                    <div class="otherinputs"><input type="radio" value="Male" checked name="gender"> <span>Male</span> <input type="radio" value="Female" name="gender"> <span>Female</span> </div>
                </div>



                <div>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password"  placeholder="Enter Your Password" id="password" name="password" required="required">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password"  placeholder="Enter Your Password Again" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" required="required">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>Captcha</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Code" id="captcha" name="captcha" class="inputcaptcha" required="required">
                    <img src="demo_captcha.php" class="imgcaptcha" alt="captcha"  />
                    <img src="images/refresh.png" alt="reload" class="refresh" />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>&nbsp;</label>
                    <div class="otherinputs" ><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1" class="submit"> &nbsp; &nbsp;</div>
                </div>





            </div>
            </form>
        </div>

</div>  
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

> demo_captcha.php

```
<?php

session_start();

function getRandomWord($len = 5) {
    $word = array_merge(range('0', '9'), range('A', 'Z'));
    shuffle($word);
    return substr(implode($word), 0, $len);
}

$ranStr = getRandomWord();



$height = 35; //CAPTCHA image height
$width = 150; //CAPTCHA image width
$font_size = 24; 

$image_p = imagecreate($width, $height);
$graybg = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 245, 245, 245);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 34, 34, 34);

imagettftext($image_p, $font_size, -2, 15, 26, $textcolor, 'fonts/mono.ttf', $ranStr);
//imagestring($image_p, $font_size, 5, 3, $ranStr, $white);
$_SESSION["vercode"] = $ranStr;
imagepng($image_p);
imagedestroy($image_p);

?>
```

> submit_demo_captcha

```
<?php
session_start();
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="1234";
$dbname="form";
$con=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

if(($_REQUEST['captcha'] == $_SESSION['vercode'])){
    $lname  =$_POST['lname'];
    $fname  =   $_POST['fname'];
    $gender =   $_POST['gender'];
    $username   =$_POST['username'];
    $email  =$_POST['email'];
    $dob    =$_POST['dob'];
    $password   =$_POST['password'];

    //Here you can write your sql insert statement. 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO form.form1 (fname,gender,lname,mname,email,dob,password) VALUES('$fname','$gender','$lname','$username','$email','$dob','$password')";
     if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

        alert("Data Submitted Successfully.");
        }
        else{
        alert("wrong captcha code!");
            }
}


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.

Comment: You got any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> submit_demo_captcha.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="1234";
$dbname="form";
$con=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

if(($_REQUEST['captcha'] == $_SESSION['vercode'])){
    $lname  =$_REQUEST['lname'];
    $fname  =   $_REQUEST['fname'];
    $gender =   $_REQUEST['gender'];
    $username   =$_REQUEST['username'];
    $email  =$_REQUEST['email'];
    $dob    =$_REQUEST['dob'];
    $password   =$_REQUEST['password'];

    //Here you can write your sql insert statement. 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO form.form1 (fname,gender,lname,mname,email,dob,password) VALUES('$fname','$gender','$lname','$username','$email','$dob','$password')";
     if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

echo 1;         }
        else{
echo 0;         }
}


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

and

> signup.php

```
 $.post("submit_demo_captcha.php?"+$("#register").serialize(), { }, function(response){
        if(response==1){
           $(".imgcaptcha").attr("src","demo_captcha.php?_="+((new Date()).getTime()));
           clear_form();
           alert("Data Submitted Successfully.")
        }else{
           alert("wrong captcha code!");
        }
    });
```